# Sending images with python sockets, images brocken

Tags: python, image, sockets

I wanted to make a client, that sends images and a list of strings to an server.
First I wanted to put eerything in one List, and make it one string with pickle, so I can send it.
But unfortunatley, the string became to big for pickle to handle, so I just used two sockets, one for the list, and one for the image.

It worked, but the Image I recived is broken.

This is the original image:

[image]

And here is the copied image:

[image]

As you can see, the bottom part is not there, but the real problem is, that I can't use the image in my kivy app, while the original image work.
How can I solve this problem?

Here is the server:

```
import socket
import errno
import base64
import pickle

from PIL import Image
import StringIO

def connect(c):#recursive funktion, that deals with the errorno 11
    try:
        strings = c.recv(8192)
        return strings
    except IOError as e:
        if e.errno == errno.EWOULDBLOCK:
            connect(c)


def Main():
    host = IP
    port = 12345

    s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM, socket.IPPROTO_TCP)
    s.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET,socket.SO_REUSEADDR,1)
    s.bind((host, port))
    s.listen(5)


    while True:

        c, addr = s.accept()


        print "Connection from: " + str(addr)

        strings = connect(c)

        #gets the image
        c.send('give image')
        #c.flush()
        c.close()

        c, addr = s.accept()
        image = connect(c)
        imgname = 'test.png'

        if image == 'cusdom_image':
            with open('images.png', "rb") as imageFile:
                image = ''
                image = base64.b64encode(imageFile.read())
                print image
        fh = open(imgname, "wb")
        fh.write(image.decode('base64'))
        fh.close()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    Main()
```

And here is the client:

```
import socket
import base64
import pickle

from PIL import Image
import StringIO
import os, sys

ip = '138.106.181.133'
port = 12345
print 'Add event executed'
s = socket.socket()#makes socket for the first time
s.connect((ip, port))

image_path = '/home/gilgamesch/PTTT/icon.png'

print os.getcwd()
olddir = os.getcwd()
os.chdir('/')
print os.getcwd()

new_list = ['Some', 'random', 'string', 'list', ]
new_compact_list = pickle.dumps(new_list)
s.send(new_compact_list)

recived = s.recv(1023)

if image_path != '':
    with open(image_path, "rb") as imageFile:
        image_data = base64.b64encode(imageFile.read())
        print 'open worked'
else:
    image_data = 'cusdom_image'

os.chdir(olddir)

if recived == 'give image':
    s.close()
    s = socket.socket()#remakes socket to send image
    s.connect((ip, port))
    s.sendall(image_data)


s.close()
```

And By the way, the bitcode is fine, when the client reads it, I tested it, it gets broken, when it is send to the server.

Comment: are you sure the data you send is not larger than 8192 bytes (that is what you read in `connect`)?

Comment: Thank you, I set the bytes to 16384(twice the size) and it worked

Comment: Unpicklicng objects you recieve from source taht you do not trust totally should be avoided for security. Better use json (in the standard library) instead of pickle. For exchanging data via JSON you can use the fact that there are no line-breaks in normal json.dumps output so just add a newline at each end of message (after json.dumps) and to make sure you got a complete message just check for a newline in the string (before json.loads)

Comment: how can I send json string over sockets?

Comment: You could do `wf=s.makefile("w",encoding="utf8");json.dump(yourstuff,wf,ensure_ascii=False);wf.write("\n")` for sending and `rf=s.makefile("r",encoding="utf8");yourstuff=json.loads(rf.readline())` for reading. (As json does not support binary data directly, you would have to encode binary data for transmission - like the image - eg with base64)

Comment: so what variable should I send?

Comment: You currently are sending pickled `new_list` in the client and you could send/receive the list containing `image_data` like you first wanted ("... client, that sends images and a list of strings to an server. First I wanted to put eerything in one List ...").